# Recursive function returning bool

Tags: c++, arrays, function, recursion, boolean

I can't understand the following recursive function returning a  `bool`.

```
 bool p(int a[], int inf, int sup) {
    if(sup==inf)
        if(a[inf]>0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    int m=(inf+sup)/2;
    bool left=p(a,inf,m);
    bool right=p(a,m+1,sup);
    return left && right;
}
```

It should return true if all the elements in (inf, sup) are positive or else false, but I can't see how the elements that are not at the two extrema of the array are considered, since the condition that is tested is that `a[inf]>0` and inf is not changed during recursion for `left`, while it gets values only in the right part of the array for `right`.

So basically, since it is different from easier recursions (like the factorial or Fibonacci) I can't understand how recursion works here: I tried to start from the base case and go on to the second step but it is unclear how to proceed.

Can anyone suggest me how to follow the recursion in this case to understand how this function returns true iff all the elements in (inf, sup) are positive?

Comment: `if(a[inf]>0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;` is needlessly verbose. Just do `return a[inf] > 0;`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I get the impression that the author of this code is not here.  If I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: thats a weird example for recursion. A simple loop is certainly better for this case, i would suggest you to pick a different example, the principle with this kind of bisection is always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always useful to try run the code for small arrays and then notice a pattern.

Algorithm definitely works for sup = inf (size = 1) and sup = inf + 1 (size = 2);

Consequently it works for size = 3, because you split your array in two (sizes 2 and 1) and we have already established that the code works for these smaller sizes.

Basically, if you know that Algo (size = k) and Algo (size = k - 1) return correct results then so do Algo (size = 2k = k + k) and Algo (size = 2k - 1 = k + (k - 1)).

And so Algo (n) works for every n.

This near-mathematical reasoning is called "mathematical induction".

Answer (score 1):

- If the collection has **one element**, return the answer for that element.  No recusion is needed to further simplify the problem.
- If the collection has **more than one element**, split the collection in half and recurse on each half.

Every element in the collection will eventually be considered as a one-element collection.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the following array

```
int a[5] = [2, 1, -3, 7, 4];
p(a, 0, 4)
```

the call to p is divided into 2 calls as `m = (0 + 4) / 2 = 2` :

`bool left=p(a,inf,m);` calls `p(a, 0, 2)`

and

`bool right=p(a,m+1, sup);` triggers `p(a, 3, 4)`

Note that the same array is being passed as argument in the subsequent calls and only the arguments `inf` and `sup` and changed.

Since in both cases `inf` and `sup` are still not equal we call calculate `m` :

```
p(a, 0, 2)       |||   p(a, 3, 4)
m = (0+2)/2 = 1  |||   m' = (3+4)/2 = 3
```

2 new calls are issued in each branches:

```
p(a, 0, 1)  ||  p(a, 2, 2)  |||  p(a, 3, 3)  ||  p(a, 4, 4)
```

When `inf` and `sup` are equal, it returns whether the element in the array is strictly positive. When it is not, it continues splitting:

```
p(a, 0, 0) | p(a, 1, 1) || false ||| true || true
true       | true       || false ||| true || true
```

In the end, the result is a boolean AND operation on every one of them:

```
true && true && false && true && true = false
```

I hope you could follow this.

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't see how the elements that are not at the two extrema of
>   the array are considered, ...

One way to convince your self is to step through the code with a debugger.

I don't resist gdb, but sometimes I prefer make the code itself report.

I add reports to interesting places.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>


class T547_t
{
   int depth = 0;

public:

   int exec()
      {
         //          0  1   2  3  4
         int a[5] = {2, 1, -3, 7, 4};

         std::cout << "\n  " << (p(a,0,4) ? "\n  true" : "\n  false") 
                   << "\n" << std::endl;

         // repeat test with all positive values

         int b[5] = {2, 1,  3, 7, 4};

         std::cout << "\n  " << (p(b,0,4) ? "\n  true" : "\n  false")
                   << "\n" << std::endl;

         return 0;
      }


private: // methods

   std::string show(int a[], int inf, int sup)
      {
         std::stringstream ss;
         depth += 1;
         ss << "a[" << inf << "," << sup << "]  "  
            << depth << std::setw(3+depth)<< "  ";
         for (int i = inf; i <= sup; ++i)
            ss << a[i] << " ";
         return ss.str();
      }


   bool p(int a[], int inf, int sup)
      {
         std::cout << "\n  " << show(a, inf, sup) << std::flush;
         if(sup==inf)
         {
            if(a[inf]>0) { depth -= 1; return true;  }
            else         { depth -= 1; return false; }
         }
         int      m = (inf+sup) / 2;
         bool  left = p (a, inf, m);
         bool right = p (a, m+1, sup);
         depth -= 1 ;
         return (left && right);
      }
    // 1 line added to beginning of method p

}; // class T547_t


int main(int , char** )
{
   T547_t   t547;
   return  t547.exec();
}
```

The output shows:

```
  a[0,4]  1    2 1 -3 7 4 
  a[0,2]  2     2 1 -3 
  a[0,1]  3      2 1 
  a[0,0]  4       2 
  a[1,1]  4       1 
  a[2,2]  3      -3 
  a[3,4]  2     7 4 
  a[3,3]  3      7 
  a[4,4]  3      4 

  false


  a[0,4]  1    2 1 3 7 4 
  a[0,2]  2     2 1 3 
  a[0,1]  3      2 1 
  a[0,0]  4       2 
  a[1,1]  4       1 
  a[2,2]  3      3 
  a[3,4]  2     7 4 
  a[3,3]  3      7 
  a[4,4]  3      4 

  true
```

Clearly all values are visited.